# Are "How do I do X in C++" questions asking to recommend a library if X not covered in Standard C++?

Tags: discussion, questions

Today I saw [Get the IP Address of local computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122208/get-the-ip-address-of-local-computer). It asks how to get an IP address in C++ in general - not a specific OS. However, there is **no networking layer** in C++, so there is no C++ way to do it.

Any answers would be reduced to enumerating and compiling lists of APIs and external libraries that can be used in a C++ program. Wouldn't that fall under **Recommending a library close-reason**?

And keep in mind that those questions intentionally don't specify an OS where the question would make sense. They don't ask "How do I find an IP address in WinAPI?", they ask how to do it in C++.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your concern. Could you please be more explicit?

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae What I was trying to say is - since there is no networking layer in C++, the only proper answer is "You can't do it at all, not in C++". You can do it "in Winapi", you can do it "in Linux", but that is not the same as "in C++". When you say "in C++" it must mean it should work on any platform that a C++ program can possibly run on - including hardware without an OS (C++ can be used for embedded programming). To do something "in C++", you must restrict yourself to only the Standard Library.

Comment: Forgive my approximate English, but I think by that logic you can close the vast majority of the C++ questions, because nearly all of them are about things not covered by the stdlib: networking, parallelism/concurrency, display, filesystem, etc. The proper answer to "how do I get the IP address of the local computer with C++" can very well be "it's not covered by C++ itself, see with your OS (if any) provided API, here's an example for Linux". Answering "you can't, there are no IP addresses in C++", really isn't helpful, even if the standard has no knowledge of what an IP address is.

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae Not really. If I saw a new question, I would ask OP what OS, API, or library he is using, and retag it accordingly. The problem is that for those 2-3 years old questions it's too late to do that. Keep in mind that questions asking for external libraries are now off-topic, and such a question would boil down to that.

Comment: Relevant codegolf: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44278/debunking-stroustrups-debunking-of-the-myth-c-is-for-large-complicated-pro See especially the comments on the C++ answer.

Answer (score 8):

On one hand, it's true that neither the C or C++ standard, taken in isolation, provides ways to do these things with guaranteed 100% portability to every conforming implementation of C or C++.

On the other hand, it's also true that part of the joy of standards is there are so many to choose from, including things like POSIX and SUS (both of which standardize interfaces to things like networking and file systems).

Yet another fact is that few people really care about writing code that's truly guaranteed to be 100% portable to every possible conforming implementation of C or C++.

That leads to the direct answer to the question you asked. There are really two choices: you can provide answers using things like Qt and/or Boost that are portable to a wide enough variety of systems that they're likely to meet most people's needs and/or you can leave a comment asking the OP what platforms/OSes he needs to support and what libraries he's using and/or willing to use.

It's always possible that the OP will reply that he needs code portable to absolutely everything, and can't use *any* libraries or other standards to help. In that (rare) case, you can pretty much point back at the language standard, and say: "sorry, that's all there is." Most people have a lot more flexibility than that though, so most such questions do have perfectly good and reasonable answers.

Comment: But in that case shouldn't the question simply be edited to say "How do I do X in Boost/Qt" and retagged? Wouldn't it make more sense to split it in 2-3 questions, one for each relevant library/API?

Comment: Those could make sense, but only rarely (IMO). In most cases, people have end requirements in mind (e.g. "must run on Windows, Linux and Mac OS"). The title should help others who have similar problems find questions that have already been asked. Putting the library name into the title means they can only find the question if they already know the answer.

Answer (score 4):

There is a networking layer in C++. It's just third party or vendor specific. e.g. WinSock and POSIX sockets are valid C++. Likewise there are multiple cross platform C++ libraries for interfacing with networking such as Boost.Asio.

Nevertheless, I disagree with your assertion in general. Not everything is defined by the C++ standard and that's fine. There are so many things that you can do in C++ that are vendor specific but have cross platform layers that being this pedantic helps no one.

My point here is that just because it's not standard doesn't mean that it isn't possible to do in the language called C++. There are proprietary extensions, many vendor libraries, many dialects of C++ in general that making this distinction is rather moot. For those who want to discuss C++ in its absolute standard way already has a tag to do this -- it's called [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer). Certain vendor specific dialects of C++ also have their own tag such as [c++-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cli).

Answer (score 3):

The "recommendations for off-site resources" close reason has never been meant to prevent answers from recommending libraries, if that's the best way to do it.

Whether to use a library, and which library to use, is a judgment call, and expert answerers are in the right place to make that call.

A question which asks for libraries without describing the problem is useless, because there's no basis for choosing one approach over another.  "Recommends an off-site resource" is just a more convenient way of saying "Your question isn't descriptive enough", that bypasses the complaints over how descriptive is enough.

A question which asks for libraries AND completely describes the problem is answerable but silly.  What if there's a better approach that doesn't use a library?  Just take out the "find me a library" portion, and such a question remains answerable and on-topic.  And the answers might involve libraries, that's ok.